# Get every IP except for the loopback device

Tags: shell, ssh, ip

I need to get every IP of an host PC over the shell, except for the loopback or localhost devices.

If I use `ip addr show` I have the loopback devices with it. Also I cannot ask for the `ip addr show [device]` because I actually don't know the device name.

Later I following to get only the ips.

```
ip addr | grep \"inet\" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

Comment: please note that `awk` can `grep`and `cut`, your expression can be rewrite as `ip addr | awk '$1 == "inet"  { split($2,I,"/"); print I[1]}'` (which also yield lo0, but filter out ipv6).

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used.

```
ip addr show scope global
```

I actually do not know if I'll miss a IP in environment with more complicated setups but for my simple test network it should work.

Actually I didn't found the something like everything but not loopback. But even if I started with that idea. This is good enough for now.